# 'culture someone' meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a Family Guy's episode, Season 3 Episode 13, Peter starts acting politely and behaves himself in his father-in-law's party also trying to act like the rich and blend. Suprised by this, Lois's father asks her how this happened and she replied, *"he's cultured himself like Julia Roberts in Pretty Woman."* I've checked the meaning of [culture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culture) in verb sense and found a couple of definitions that I'm not sure exactly which one fits the context esp. with a reflexive pronoun after the verb and considering that Peter doesn't really like his in-laws. If you want to paraphrase this sentence how would you go? Is this standard using of the word *culture* or simply an improvisation here and not a common usage?

Comment: I think it's very black humour, since you *culture* bacteria -- life-forms not known for their intelligence. Paraphrase it and you lose the joke.

Comment: It's a joke. Agree.

Comment: I don't think any of the answers below point out that the quote has the meaning _"He, himself, is cultured."_ This is not a use of the verb _culture_ as a transitive. _Cultured_ is adjectival here.

Comment: @P. E. Dent that's an interesting point of view and knowing Lois' good-natured way of speaking, it makes even more sense although let me quote the whole thing that made it a little hard to understand to me. You might have seen Pretty Woman and it probably makes more sense to you. Lois said, "he's cultured himself **like Julia Roberts in Pretty Woman**."

Comment: +1 for all. Thank you I got my answer. @Mick Now I got the joke ;)

Comment: For future reference, you should include the episode number/title, or a larger portion of the dialogue. As it stands, "He, himself, is cultured." does not make sense as a response to the question "How did this happen?". At the moment, an improvisation, as J.R. puts it, makes the most sense, in my opinion. Another slightly less accurate way to put it would be "He educated himself."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say is an improvisation. The word *culture* isn't generally used as a verb in this context.

As a paraphrase, I'd suggest:

> *He's decided to become a more cultured person.*

Answer (score 3):

I would paraphrase it as:

> He's cultivated himself.

[cultivate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cultivate):

> 5. To acquire, develop, or refine, as by education: cultivating a posh accent.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, I think that 
 ***[integrate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/integrate)*** is often used with a very similar connotation;

> - to mix with and join society or a group of people, often changing to suit their way of life, habits, and customs:
>
>   - *He seems to find it difficult to integrate socially.
>       It's very difficult to integrate yourself into a society whose culture is so different from your own.
>       Children are often very good at integrating into a new culture.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

It is an improvisation, with the meaning "He has made an effort to become cultured." Google search throws up just one additional example: "He's cultured himself in all types of music."

It sounds a little patronising, so don't use it at home.